# java syntax error on token

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax

Hello i am beginner in java
How can i solve the error  : ( Syntax error on token "a", delete this token)
in this program on eclipse ?

```
package practises;
import java.util.*;
public class T_5_2 {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main (String [] args){
        float C;
        System.out.print("Enter temprature by centigrade : ");
        C=in.nextFloat();
        double F=ctof(C);
        System.out.print("temperature by far = " + F);
    }
    public static float ctof (float a){
        return (float) (1.8a+3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
return (float) (1.8a+3);
```

To

```
return  1.8f * a+3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your ctof method like this;

```
public static float ctof (float a){
            return (float) (1.8*a+3);
    }
```

or

```
 public static float ctof (float a){
                return 1.8f*a+3;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`return (float) (1.8a+3);` is not valid syntax. You should use `return (float) (1.8 * a + 3);` instead.